# Should errors and loading be stored in store or state?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm having issues trying to figure out where I should store stuff like loading or errors state.

Let's say I have a react component that fetches data from a server on mount. What I'm doing is dispatching an action `FETCH_SOME_DATA`, which will handle the async part thanks to a middleware, which in turn will dispatch a `FETCH_SOME_DATA_SUCCESS` or `FETCH_SOME_DATA_FAILURE` depending on the async request's outcome.

Now, what I want to do is showing the user something is happening while I'm fetching the data, so I need something that let me know something is loading. I guess I could have a reducer react to my `FETCH_SOME_DATA` action and update my store to toggle an `isLoading` value, but here's where I'm having issues: to me, this shouldn't be in the store, but in the component's state.

I guess that may be weird, so here's why: let's say I'm displaying the last 5 articles of a blog and the whole list (paginated), I don't want both of them to display a loader if the user clicks on "see more articles" in my whole list...

Same thing with errors, really. Let's say my news fetch failed. I don't want both my components to display an error. They should be independent - each component should try and fetch its data and react to errors accordingly.

I hope I'm being clear... I guess I have a strong opinion on the subject but everyone seems to think differently but I don't understand why. Hope you guys explain to me where to store "temporary data" and why.

Thanks!

Comment: honestly components have their own state for a reason. if you are requesting something you can set a state locally that shows some loading view and when the request comes in (you will know because the prop that contains the data from the request will be filled) you can set your state back to not show the loading.

Answer (score 0):

One of `redux` [priciples](http://redux.js.org/docs/introduction/ThreePrinciples.html) is that you have a single source of truth. Your app will have one and only one state - and this state is managed by the store. Your state will not only contain data fetched from server but also informations about the current status of your UI. So if you want to render a loading indicator for a currently active async request, this info will be stored in the state and not in the component.

Comment: I think my problem is that I can't see `isLoading` and `errors` data as part of the application state, though. To me it's pretty much just temporary display data. :/

Answer (score 0):

Whether you're fetching a list of post or each post individually, your store is responsible to reflect what happened. If there is some  error when fetching data, you could set a "status" flag to "error" in your posts list reducer or on each post item individually.

Your components are reponsible to display something to the user depending on the current state. Your `PostList` component could have a prop `status` received from the store and displaying some useful information to the end user. The same goes for each individual post, one of their possible ui state is an error state so you should have a prop defining this ui state for your component in order to let him display an error to the end user.